# Why does Tom not want to leave even if his son is dying?

Tags: character, interstellar

Quick recap of Tom's life in *Interstellar*: everyone he loves dies. He loses his mother, his father, his first son and his grandfather.
After his dad spends Tom's childhood making it clear he prefers Murph, he then abandons the family and leaves Tom his worthless farm and truck. After a life of pain, Murph berates Tom for being stuck in his old-fashioned ways even though that's all he knows because he wasn't allowed to pursue higher education.

But why does Tom not want to leave even if his son is dying?

Comment: Well, interesting recap of Tom's life, but I can't really see the actual question you're asking. Is it something like this: http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/32479/49?

Comment: No, that is related to doctor, my question is why does he so not want to leave the city? if not for him, atleast for his son's sake

Comment: What city?  He lives on a farm in the countryside.

Comment: Not a bad premise, but this question sounds more like a rant than anything. Maybe with some tidying up, it can be salvaged.

Comment: `After his dad spends Tom's childhood making it clear he prefers Murph...` Wait when did this happen?

Comment: He's stubborn. Questions about character motivations...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The farm isn't worthless - Tom and his family are actually able to make a living off of it, and it's both the family's home and their main (possibly only) source of income. Much the same reasons that many people in real life stay in poor and/or dangerous areas. The combination of strong emotional ties to "home" (potential emotional baggage related to individual family members aside) and concern/fear regarding "I may not be making the best living here and now, but will I be able to support myself/my family at all if we uproot?" makes for very powerful motivation to *not* move. (Plus - as vaguely referenced in the comments - a large part of Murph's argument for Tom & co to leave is to get medical attention, and Tom is wary of the doctors/kinds of medical attention that his sister is advocating for.)